# How can we center an iframe inside an absolute positionned div

Tags: html, css, css-position, center

I tried to put the `iframe` tag inside an `a` tag and set its css to `text-align:center`, but it didn't work

Edit Sorry, I mislead I have an `iframe`

```
<div>
    <iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <button type="button">Ajouter la vidéo...</button>
</div>
```

the `div` is itself centered and has class

```
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 30%;
margin-left: -200px;
z-index: 3;
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` ? If you post your markup, it would be easier to offer suggestions.

Comment: your question and its description does not match.. u r asking about DIV in question and describing about anchor in description. What do you want exactly?

Comment: give `img` tag `display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @Mr_Green margin auto won't work unless the img is set to block and assigned some fixed width

Comment: @Mr.Alien that is why I mentioned `display: inline-block`... but I am not sure...

Comment: @Mr_Green Sorry I mislead I have not an img but an iframe...

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you I set it like a block and it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

```
img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an inline element, you need to make a `block` level element, as it is `inline`, your `img` has no space to get centered, so make it `block` or `inline-block` and than use `text-align: center;` for `a`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjSgB/)

> Note: If you are using `block` it will take up 100% space, if you are
>   using `inline-block;` you NEED to specify some `width` to the element,
>   else it's of no use

---

As you updated your question, here's a new [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqtda/)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your CSS code can only make me guess it.

An `a` tag is an inline element which will only take the width that it needs. So when adding an image to it, the width will be as width as the image. The `text-align: center` does work, but you can't see it.

Changing your `a` to an (inline-)block can fix your problem, check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ALbUZ/).

```
.imgLink {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```